# Azure Mobile Services iOS framework shows login even if logged in

Tags: ios, authentication, azure-mobile-services

I use the `client.currentUser` property to find out if the user is logged in. The issue is that the this property is always `nil` on startup. As a result I have to start the login sequence that completes without user interaction but as a side effect *shows the login screen for a short time*.

How can I prevent the login screen from showing if the login completes with out user interaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the `client.currentUser` value locally after the first time someone logs in. After that, you can set `client.currentUser` from your local store, but you'll need to work out what to do when the token expires.

[From a Josh Twist blog post](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Setting_the_auth_token_in_the_Mobile_Services_client_and_caching_the_user_rsquo_s_identity_Day_10_.aspx):

```
// Objective C
MSClient *client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:@"<your-app-url>"
                                     withApplicationKey:@"<your-app-key>"];

client.currentUser = [MSUser alloc] initWithUserId:@"Foo:123456789";
client.currentUser.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken = @"<your-users-JWT>";
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about this but note from the login method's documentation: `While the |currentUser| property can be set directly, the |login*| and |logout| methods are more convenient and recommended for non-testing use.` I'd expect the framework to provide the means for me to handle this correctly. Or at least provide corresponding callbacks. I have to hack again, fantastic...